# How to disable hardware button for Particular page in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have written `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` for all states in `app.run()`.So when app intialize it register back button for all pages .Now i want to change the hardware back button functionality for particular page in the controller of that page .How can i do that without registering all other pages again.

```
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
        if ($state.current.name == 'app.homepage' || $state.current.name == 'app.loginUser') {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        } else if ($state.current.name == "app.contacts" || $state.current.name == 'app.carDocuments' || $state.current.name == 'app.tracking' || $state.current.name == 'app.logBook'|| $state.current.name == 'app.geofence' || $state.current.name == 'app.walktocar' || $state.current.name == 'app.dashboard' || $state.current.name == 'app.geofenceTest' || $state.current.name == 'app.settings' || $state.current.name == 'app.about' || $state.current.name == 'app.tripDetail' ||      $state.current.name == 'app.newTripDetail'|| $state.current.name == 'app.followMeTrack' || $state.current.name == 'app.followMe' || $state.current.name == 'app.maintainance' || $state.current.name == 'app.faultHistory' || $state.current.name == 'app.routeType'|| $state.current.name == 'app.poi') {
            if ($rootScope.isDeletePage == "true") {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('callOriginalView');
                $rootScope.isDeletePage = "false";
            } else {
                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableBack: true
                });

                $state.go('app.homepage');
            }

        } else {
            $ionicHistory.goBack();
        }
    }, 100);
```

So if i write $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction again then i have to write all this code again to register. How  i can override the back button for particular page only ih his controller

Comment: Add your sample code

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we should not override default action but if you want to change it's functionality, make sure to perform single functionality with that.

```
  // Disable BACK button on home
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($state.current.name=="app.home"){ // here instead of "app.home" mention state name of particular page
      //navigator.app.exitApp(); // this is for exiting app
      // write your code that you wish to do
      event.preventDefault() // do nothing
    }
    else if($state.current.name=="app.settings"){ 

      // write your code that you wish to do

    }
    else if($state.current.name=="app.contact"){ 

      // write your code that you wish to do

    }
    else {
      navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
  }, 100);
```

If you want to have different actions in each page, have a function in service and call it from different controllers by passing configuration like callback function. So that, you need not to register in each and every controller

Comment: ,but with your solution it will override the other pages register back buttton too ,i have to register them again too, lets say if for particular state as "app.settings" on clicking back button i have to move it to home page and i already register this in app.js during time of app loading now i dont want to register all buttons again

Comment: Check uopdated answer.

Comment: I already written all these conditions during initialization of the app only once i am not registering it again and again ,But for particular controller i want to override the if condition ,and dont want to rewrite all these if conditions.

Comment: How many actions you want to do with backButton in a single state? :(